# Virtualbox 4.2 not booting any virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and my Virtualbox-4.1 stopped working. So I downloaded the Virtualbox-4.2 deb for Raring ringtail from their website and installed it. When I start Virtualbox, it starts fine. On trying to start a Virtual Machine I get this error.

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.
```

On running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` I get:

```
farhat@palantir:~$ /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                           
 * Cannot unload module vboxdrv
```

What should be done here?

Thanks,

ETA:

```
farhat@palantir$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -e virtualbox -e linux-headers -e dkms
ii  dkms                                      2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu2                     all          Dynamic Kernel Module Support Framework
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-26                    3.8.0-26.38                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-26-generic            3.8.0-26.38                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                     3.8.0.26.44                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  virtualbox-4.1                            4.1.26-84997~Ubuntu~precise            amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-4.2                            4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~raring             amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep -e virtualbox -e linux-headers -e dkms`.

Comment: Did you reboot after purging virtualbox OSE edition?

Comment: added the output of dpkg and I didn't reboot after purging virtualbox-4.1

Comment: Tried rebooting as well. No change.

Comment: This answer helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912

Answer (score 6):

This command must run with root privileges. Try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Also try purging everything:

```
apt-get purge virtualbox-4.1 virtualbox-4.2
```

then reboot, reinstall VirtualBox 4.2, and run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to install any missing dependencies.

Run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` again to make sure the VirtualBox kernel module is installed.

Comment: I get the same message and VirtualBox still doesn't work even after running with `sudo`.

Comment: Please note that VirtualBox should NOT BE RUNNING when you run the vboxdrv script. Close the program and run the script with root privileges.

Comment: I had shut down Virtualbox while using the `sudo /etc...` command.

Comment: @Farhat answer updated.

Comment: I followed the updated steps. Still getting the same error on running vboxdrv and Virtualbox gives the same error as before. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a good hint on this one. I've had a 64 bit kernel on my 32 bit system for some funny reason. Nothing I did managed to avert this annoyance but once I reverted back to a 32 bit kernel all of a sudden everything popped back into place.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old question, but I recently had similar issue with Virtual Box 5.0. Reinstalling Virtual Box using '.deb' from [their website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) helped.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove all Virtualbox-related Softwares/Dependencies by running this:

```
sudo apt-get  remove virtualbox
```

then reboot your OS and reinstall downloaded version.

It happens when you have an installed app with same name as one of Virtualbox dependencies has.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)

Credits go to @Ravexina https://askubuntu.com/users/264781/ravexina)

But it's the definite solution to the problem.

---

It seems that your installation version of virtualbox is for 32-bit architecture while you are running 64-bit operation system which can be the cause of this problem.

My workaround would be to remove the installed version from PPA, and installing virtualbox from official repositories.

To remove virtualbox, run:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*
```

After that make sure there is no other version installed on your system by:

```
dpkg -l virtualbox* | grep ^i
```

You shouldn't get any output, also you can try to run virtualbox to make sure it's not installed.

Then remove all related PPAs from your sources.list and sources.list.d directory. ex:

```
mkdir ~/apt-tmp
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp
```

Make sure there is nothing except official repositories sources in `/etc/sources.list`.

And update your sources:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now we can search to see which versions are available to install:

```
apt-cache madison virtualbox | grep -iv sources
```

Which produces an output like this:

```
virtualbox | 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 | http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
virtualbox | 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 | http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Then I would install the last version mentioned in xenial-updates:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox=5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2
```

Also sudo apt install virtualbox, would be fine, but I would go with the above command to make sure my desired version is going to be installed.

And after all, check that the correct version is installed.

From command line:

```
dpkg -l virtualbox* | grep ^i

ii  virtualbox                     5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

From GUI: to make sure correct version is running.

Help menu -> about virtualbox