# VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox `Version 5.1.18 r114002 (Qt5.5.1)` on Ubuntu `16.04 LTS`. To virtualize everything (Kali, Windows 10).

I encounter the following error:

> RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)
>
> The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox.
>   The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful.
>   Executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and
>   the PUEL version of VirtualBox.
>
> where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4
>   VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver
>   doesn't match the version of the user.
>   [image]

- What causes this problem?
- How can this problem be solved?

When i run `dpkg --list virtualbox-*` in terminal, I get:

```
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold  
 | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend     
 |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)  
 ||/ Name       Version      Architecture Description
 +++-==============-============-============-================================= 
 rc  virtualbox-5.0 5.0.32-11293 i386         Oracle VM VirtualBox 
 rc  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.18-11400 i386         Oracle VM VirtualBox  
 un virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
 un virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
 un virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? it says executing `/sbin/vboxconfig` my correct this.  last version of virtualbox in repository is: `5.0.32`, I suggest installing the vbox from offical repository.

Comment: The error indicates that your virtual machine was installed in a VirtualBox version different to your present installation. This could be from mixing OSE (Ubuntu repositories) and PUEL version (after installing from Oracle including the extension pack), or from a different architecture (32 vs. 64 bit) - hard to say without knowing what you did before the error occured.

Comment: @Ravexina I have removed `5.1.18` and installed `5.0.32` but get previous Error.

Comment: @Ravexina  I run `dpkg --list virtualbox-*` and updated my question.

Comment: @Takkat  I run `dpkg --list virtualbox-*` and updated my question.

Comment: Seems you still got 5.1 installed, run: `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge virtualbox-5.1`, then remove the unofficial repositories, and install virtualbox.

Comment: @Ravexina  I get this error again. ` dpkg --list virtualbox-*` result:  `
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  virtualbox-5.0 5.0.32-11293 i386         Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
`

Comment: what is the output of `uname -m`

Comment: @Ravexina `x86_64`

Comment: @AliHesari: the output of `apt-cache madison virtualbox | grep -iv source`

Comment: @Ravexina No output.

Comment: @AliHesari: do it without grep: `apt-cache madison virtualbox`, and after opening virtualbox from `help` menu choose `about`, check what version you are running.

Comment: @Ravexina No output!! VirtualBox Version 5.1.18 r114002 (Qt5.5.1)

Comment: @AliHesari so you still running the wrong version. run: `whereis virtualbox` see what versions are available, try the right one ;)

Comment: I just had this exact problem (same vbox version, same ubuntu version). I followed the advice of @Ravexina (purging, ensuring 5.1.18 is completely removed, then installing 5.0.32 from the Ubuntu repository). Mine now works properly.

Comment: @AliHesari: did you tried `whereis virtualbox` to locate the right version?

Comment: @Ravexina yea, The output is:  `virtualbox: /usr/bin/virtualbox /usr/lib/virtualbox /usr/share/virtualbox`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Read This first!

*Please note that this answer is intended to **specifically** solve the original poster's problem when typical solutions like running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` or removing `virtualbox-dkms` and installing `dkms` does not work.*

Please first try these simple workarounds, these might help you right away.

---

It seems that your installation version of virtualbox is for 32-bit architecture while you are running 64-bit operation system which can be the cause of this problem.

My workaround would be to remove the installed version from PPA, and installing virtualbox from official repositories.

To remove virtualbox, run:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*
```

After that make sure there is no other version installed on your system by:

```
dpkg -l 'virtualbox*' | grep ^i
```

You shouldn't get any output, also you can try to run virtualbox to make sure it's not installed.

Then remove all related PPAs from your `sources.list` and `sources.list.d` directory. ex:

```
mkdir ~/apt-tmp
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp
```

*Make sure there is nothing except official repositories sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.*

And update your sources:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now we can search to see which versions are available to install:

```
apt-cache madison virtualbox | grep -iv sources
```

Which produces an output like this:

```
virtualbox | 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 | http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
virtualbox | 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 | http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Then I would install the last version mentioned in `xenial-updates`:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox=5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2
```

Also `sudo apt install virtualbox`, would be fine, but I would go with the above command to make sure my desired version is going to be installed.

And after all, check that the correct version is installed.

**From command line:**

```
dpkg -l virtualbox* | grep ^i

ii  virtualbox                     5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

**From GUI:** to make sure correct version is running.

Help menu -> about virtualbox

*Pay attention to green highlight*

[image: vbox]

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. I run `apt-cache madison virtualbox | grep -iv sources`  but I did not get output!!! no problem?

Comment: You should get an output as my example, add this commands output to your question `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp` by doing this, `sudo apt-get install` won't install any other software after. So don't forget to move it back

Comment: Ran into the same issue, with some 3rd party apt retro, thanks heaps on how to remove it! Having said that, it IS already possible, to install **5.1** in direct fashions, see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/956641/479118).

Comment: I followed your instructions and installed virtualbox but I am not able to install guest additions

Comment: @vSugumar Create a new question and explain why you're not able to install "guest additions" (add any error, etc), so we can help you ;)

Comment: thanks. how to do that with pacman? (for Manjaro linux)

Comment: Another typical solution is to reboot your computer (which worked for me).

Answer (score 118):

If you installed VirtualBox by [official manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and didn't forget to delete installed one from default Ubuntu repository.

Check if `virtualbox-dkms` is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox-dkms
```

If yes, then delete it and install `dkms`

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms && \
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Rebuild VirtualBox kernel modules:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Comment: This is the way!  This one seems like the most direct answer and worked for me here on 22.04.3LTS in Feb, 2024. 

Answer (score 11):

So, in my case, the kernel modules were not removed properly.

Here are the details:

```
root@Dell5280 [~]# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

root@Dell5280 [~]# uname -r
4.13.0-31-generic
```

Problem:

```
root@Dell5280 [~]# modinfo vboxdrv
filename: /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
version: 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130 (0x00240000)
license: GPL
description: Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author: Oracle Corporation
srcversion: 6D8B4900A693FC50489A130
depends:
name: vboxdrv
vermagic: 4.13.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
```

FIX:

```
root@Dell5280 [~]# rm /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko

root@Dell5280 [~]# modinfo vboxdrv
filename: /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'vboxdrv': No such file or directory
[1] root@Dell5280 [~]# /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.

root@Dell5280 [~]# modinfo vboxdrv
filename: /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko
version: 5.2.7 r120349 (0x00290000)
license: GPL
description: Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author: Oracle Corporation
srcversion: 4880B21EFF1B605D6402982
depends:
name: vboxdrv
vermagic: 4.13.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
parm: force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
```

After this, everything works (at least in my case)

Hope it helps.
Hide
See full activity log

I posted the reply at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1736116

Answer (score 6):

It seems you have two separate versions of VirtualBox installed on your system!

I would recommend that you fully **uninstall all versions** of VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 'virtualbox*'
```

Then reinstall directly from Oracle virtualbox. Go to the [VB download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), scroll down to "***Debian-based Linux distributions***", and follow the instructions or download VB binary package for **all distributions** and then run the installer like this:

```
cd /path/to/downloaded/file
chmod +x VirtualBox-x.x.xx-xxxxxx-Linux_xxxxx.run
./VirtualBox-x.x.xx-xxxxxx-Linux_xxxxx.run
```

Answer (score 3):

If reinstall Virtualbox not work. You should Try install or reinstall the `dkms` of Virtualbox

verify if have errors:

```
dpkg -P virtualbox-dkms
```

If you have error probably should try do:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: This left files on my machine but this removed all `autoremove --purge virtualbox*`

Comment: Wow, the thing that fixed it for me was at the very bottom...`sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*`

Comment: i did the same i.e., solely reinstalled the 'virtualbox-dkms' package  ,
but had to execute one last command afterwards in sequential order 
`>>lsmod | grep vboxdrv` resulted in nothing , 
so i had to execute  `>>modprobe vboxdrv` , then `>>lsmod | grep vboxdrv` resulted in `vboxdrv  479232  0` .
then virtualbox worked afterwards without raising an error

Answer (score 3):

a simple `apt upgrade virtualbox` worked for me

Comment: This helped to identify virtualbox-dkms was not upgraded together with virtualbox and caused version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have vbox modules loaded:

```
lsmod | grep vbox
```

On my machine, I have `vboxpci`, `vboxnetadp`, `vboxnetflt`, and `vboxdrv`

Check if they are the correct version:

```
modinfo vboxdrv
```

Very likely that the version of this module would be `5.0.32 rxxxxxx`, but you are running virtualbox 5.1

If this is not the case, this answer might not help solve your problem.

Otherwise, this might be caused by not removing the modules left over by your old-version virtualbox, and the new modules are not overwriting.

Simply remove all those old modules and reboot, and it should fix the problem:

```
# This command list all files in the same directory of the vboxdrv module
# Double check they are all vbox* modules and are outdated
# Then change "ls" to "rm" to remove all
ls $(dirname $(modinfo vboxdrv | sed -n 's/filename: *(\.*\)/\1/p'))/*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the latest version of virtualbox, you need to remove modules in the dkms folder.

**VB 5.1 and older places modules in *misc* while VB 5.0 in the fork stores them in *dkms* folder.**

1. Purge all virtualbox with **apt**
2. Check `modinfo vboxdrv` to see if it outputs **version 5.0**:

   ```
   $ modinfo vboxdrv
   filename: /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
   version: 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130 (0x00240000)
   license: GPL
   description: Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
   author: Oracle Corporation
   srcversion: 6D8B4900A693FC50489A130
   depends:
   name: vboxdrv
   vermagic: 4.13.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
    parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
   ```
3. If it does output **5.0**, delete the modules in dkms folder:

   ```
   $ sudo -i
   # sudo rmmod vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv 
   # cd /lib/modules/(kernelversion)-generic/updates/dkms
   # rm vbox*
   ```
4. Run `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` (then check whether `modinfo vboxdrv` gives the correct version)

   ```
   $ modinfo vboxdrv
   filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko
   version:        5.2.6 r120293 (0x00290000)
   license:        GPL
   description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
   author:         Oracle Corporation
   srcversion:     4880B21EFF1B605D6402982
   depends:        
   vermagic:       4.10.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
   parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

after updating to 6.0 this message also appeared. In case you didn't do it, restart your system so that all new modules be loaded into the kernel. Sometimes it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I removed virtualbox using the command given below:

`sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*`

but it did not work.

I found that the old vboxdrv mod was not getting removed and had to manually remove vboxdrv.ko from "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/".