# My desktop freezes when trying to run VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Dell Optiplex 9010, amd64, currently running xenial 16.04

I was following this thread:
[VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)

I'll try other distros. Virtualization is enabled in BIOS from what I can tell.

I'm just not sure if the host OS freezing means anything right off the bat.

I am using a 64bit guest os (Ubuntu also). I'll try Debian next (though isn't Ubuntu based on Debian/vice versa) maybe I should try 32bit

Desktop has quad core, set 1  core for VM with 1GB RAM (has 16GB)

I'll also try disabling Vt-x I saw that in the VBox setup

edit: Debian froze too

edit: will post on the Vbox forums, probably where I should have been from the start. Forgot I used to post there.