# Where does "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*" belong?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox

I'm very much a beginner using Ubuntu 16.04.

From this page, 
[VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)

I followed this instruction among others from Ravexina:

```
mkdir ~/apt-tmp
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp
```

When I finished, I noticed this warning from Asme Just:

> `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp` by doing this, sudo
>   apt-get install won't install any other software after. So don't
>   forget to move it back – Asme Just Aug 23 '17 at 8:35

To where should I move it back, and how?  I confess that I'll need the script to type.

Thanks very much.

Comment: With such non-beginner actions you can completely break and destroy your system. Take such actions with caution. Moreover with moved source lists from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` you will get obsolete/locally-installed packages and/or broken dependencies. If you want to learn by hard way - install Ubuntu on VM and play with system here (ofcourse with snapshot of clean installation).

Comment: @N0rbert Of course installing VBox in a VM is not the best thing to try ;-)

Comment: @medusa193 The post you linked to does not contain the instructions you have obviously followed.

Comment: @Bruni then I completely can't understand the main idea behind OP question ;)

Comment: Sorry.  The links were side by side in my history list; here's the correct post:  
https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912

Comment: @Bruni, sorry.  please see the comment immediately above and the now-corrected post.

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/apt-tmp
```

moves all the *contents* of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to directory `~/apt-tmp`

To move them back, you can use

```
sudo mv ~/apt-tmp/* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Note that the directory may have been empty, unless you have installed 3rd party software (since the main repositories are in a separate *file* `/etc/apt/sources.list`)

Comment: Thanks, steeldriver! Given my erroneous link, if the proper page and instructions I followed make any difference, here it is:  
https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912

Comment: @medusa193 I've seen it - but I don't understand what you're asking. Is there something still unclear?

Comment: Okay; no, nothing's unclear.  Thanks for helping a beginner; your advice apparently worked like a charm!  I really appreciate it.  :)