# Virtual box works no longer, suspect a kernel update caused this

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

Virtual box fails to boot any VMs, suspect its due to a kernel update

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
```

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (`vboxdrv`) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with `/dev/vboxdrv`. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

```
modprobe vboxdrv
```

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

when you try reinstalling the dkms

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

```
Building for 5.0.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 5.0.0-23-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/make.log for more information.
```

Make log is as follows:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-5.2.18 for kernel 5.0.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Sun Aug  4 08:04:13 IST 2019
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxHost_RTR0MemUserIsValidAddr’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.c:69:55: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
     bool fRc = access_ok(VERIFY_READ, (void *)R3Ptr, 1);
                                                       ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.c:69:16: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     bool fRc = access_ok(VERIFY_READ, (void *)R3Ptr, 1);
                ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.c:69:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/Makefile.build:515: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
Makefile:1606: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.18/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic'
```

If i try

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: have you tried purging and reinstalling vbox? make sure your VMs are backed up somewhere and run `sudo apt purge virtualbox* && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt install virtualbox`

Comment: You haven't told us what release you are using. We can see your kernel, but that's used by two releases (18.04 LTS with HWE enabled & 19.04)

Comment: You need to upgrade to the v6 series of VirtualBox; it builds fine on the 5.0 series kernels.

Comment: I see that the Bionic repositories have VBox 5.2.18, which is the same version you are running. If you installed VBox from the Bionic repositories and you are fully up-to-date but the build still fails, that's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS with 5.1.18_Ubuntu r123745

Comment: @ajgringo619 I tried updating to v6 and now I'm blocked by https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18771

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed the signs of a Secure Boot problem earlier. Disable Secure Boot in your BIOS and try again.

Comment: @Joshua Besneatte , it worked fine now:  `sudo apt purge virtualbox* && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt install virtualbox`  I did see some new packages being downloaded  The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms libgsoap-2.8.60 libqt5opengl5 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt  I couldnt figure put what the problem was, so its a clean install that fixed this.

Comment: I was on this build  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: OK, I will add that as an answer :)

Comment: @ajgringo619 Disabling Secure Boot has stopped this message appearing but I still can't run. I've purged and reinstalled Virtualbox 6 but getting "RTR3InitEx failed with RC=-1912 (rc=-1912)"

Comment: I had to do https://askubuntu.com/a/979223/59832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to purge and reinstall VirtualBox.

1. Back up your virtual machines somewhere safe.
2. Purge Virtualbox:

   ```
   $ sudo apt purge virtualbox*
   ```
3. Get rid of old deps and configs:

   ```
   $ sudo apt autoremove
   $ sudo apt autoclean
   ```
4. Install a shiny new VBox

There are two options for installing VBox. From standard repos (**Option 1**) or from a PPA (**Option 2**). Do one or the other NOT both.

**Option 1. You can install directly from the standard repos like this:**

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
```

**Option 2. Install from the PPA**

If you want the absolute latest version of VBox and any potential closed source drivers follow these steps to install from the PPA.

**4.2.1.** Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

**4.2.2.** Download Oracle public key:

```
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

**4.2.3.** Install VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

More info on PPA install [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

5. Enjoy :)

Comment: it's not works.. !!! still got same error.. !

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The kernel module can not be built.

Comment: The above command for adding the repository will have to be altered if you are not using the bionic release. Update the repo to your distro and be sure to purge the old install so you are starting with a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a old topic, but I had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04, as far as my knowledge go, is because of the Secure Boot.

I tried troubleshooting running virtualbox through temrinal, so I got a message that suggested me to run

sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

that helped me to put a signature to the kernel driver (again, if I got it right) with a guided procedure.

So far everything is working fine,I hope this could help.

If I wrote something wrong or not clear let me know :)