# How do I install Whonix

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I think Whonix is installed

but whenever i try to load it the vm gives me this

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (fRtFlags=0x10000) (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you are not mixing builds of VirtualBox from different sources.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

So I really can't tell if it's installed or not

curiosity and I don't know if it is relivent

when trying to load a vm to run rebuild the universe in it gives me this

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (fRtFlags=0x10000) (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you are not mixing builds of VirtualBox from different sources.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

two vm's similer error's and the virtual machine software is what whonix put there when i tried following the commands of some website

Comment: Did you try running the command it suggests? What happened?

Comment: what command im just seeing a bunch of code flags and a file path

Comment: /sbin/vboxconfig is probably the command @popey is referring to. It might configure Virtualbox so that your Whonix and your Virtualbox use the same Virtualbox drivers. So maybe try running /sbin/vboxconfig in your terminal and go from there. Maybe check this issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912?rq=1

Comment: Ok did that, it asked for my password about 10 times and gave the same error after doing this

Comment: neoisfree@neoisfree-B550-AORUS-ELITE-AX-V2:~$ 
/sbin/vboxconfig
rm: cannot remove '/sbin/rcvboxdrv': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/rcvboxdrv': File exists
/sbin/vboxconfig: 165: cannot create /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/sbin/rcvboxballoonctrl-service': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/rcvboxballoonctrl-service':

Comment: File exists
/sbin/vboxconfig: 165: cannot create /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/sbin/rcvboxautostart-service': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/rcvboxautostart-service': File exists
/sbin/vboxconfig: 165: cannot create /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service: Permission denied

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/sbin/rcvboxweb-service': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/rcvboxweb-service': File exists
/sbin/vboxconfig: 165: cannot create /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service: Permission deniedrm: cannot remove '/sbin/rcvboxweb-service': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/rcvboxweb-service': File exists
/sbin/vboxconfig: 165: cannot create /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service: Permission denied

Comment: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sbin/vboxconfig': Permission denied
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Cannot unload module vboxnetadp.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
neoisfree@neoisfree-B550-AORUS-ELITE-AX-V2:~$

Comment: You need to run the command using sudo

Comment: ok this is the result this time
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
neoisfree@neoisfree-B550-AORUS-ELITE-AX-V2:~$ 

however same error