# VirtualBox RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 error when i try to start Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox

I keep running into this issue with VirtualBox. Here's a screenshot.

[image: screenshot of my issue]

Comment: Did you reboot after installing VirtualBox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)